# помогите с решением задачи на C++

Tags: c++

[image: задача]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float N = 10.0;
    float A = 0.55;
    float B = 1.0;
    float step = (B-A)/N;
    for(int i =0; i<N; i++) {
        float x = A+(step*i);
        std::cout<<sqrt(pow(pow(x,4),1/5)+pow(pow(x,4-x),1/5))+log*abs(x - 20.5);
        std::cout<<"";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

поправьте меня пожалуйста если я в чем то ошибся

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы было N точек, включая крайние значения, шаг считается так:

```
float step = (B-A)/(N-1);
```

Корни можно записать через один pow, а не через пару (но это не ошибка)

```
pow(x,4.0/5) + pow(x,(4-x)/5
```

Вот это что такое `log*abs`? Ведь компилятор наверняка ругался

```
 log(abs(x - 20.5));
```

Comment: @ДаниилВоробьев Помогло?